# Regular Expression - Binary String Matches But Not When Reversed

Tags: regex

To start, it is pretty obvious that this is homework and I believe I've done my due diligence. Now I don't expect a solution to be handed to me on a silver platter, just a simple nudge in the right direction would be nice, so let me begin:

**The question is:**

> All strings over the alphabet {0, 1} where every odd-length block of
>   0's is immediately followed by an even-length block of 1's, and every
>   even-length block of 0's is immediately followed by an odd-length
>   block of 1's.

What I've been doing is working at it piece by piece, starting with:

**Match only even 0’s, odd 1’s:** `^[^0]*((00)+1(11)*)*$`

**Match only odd 0’s, even 1’s:** `^[^0]*(0(00)*(11)+)*$`

**Putting them both together:** `^[^0]*((00)+1(11)*)*(0(00)*(11)+)*$`

I thought this worked initially, but it only works with:

- 001011
- 001000010110001111, etc.
- Basically anything else that appears in the same order as how it appears in the expression which makes sense.

And not:

- 011001, etc.

What I've been stuck on is figuring out is how to have it work for the case listed above. I tried doing a positive lookahead, but it didn't seem to work.

Does anyone have any pointers?

Comment: Have you tried something like `((case 1)|(case 2))+`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're definitely on the right track.

Match only even 0’s, odd 1’s: `^(00)+1(11)*$`

Match only odd 0’s, even 1’s: `^0(00)*(11)+$`

Putting them both together: `^(((00)+1(11)*)|(0(00)*(11)+))+$`

Just for fun, here's a shorter one that fails on input `1`, `111`, `11111`... unless you count zero as an even number.

```
^((00)*(01)?1(11)*)+$
```

Answer (score 1):

Combining them both as `^[^0]*((00)+1(11)*)*(0(00)*(11)+)*$` only gets you half way, as it only works when all of the odd-0-even-1 blocks are before all of the even-0-odd-1 blocks.  What you want is a regex that matches zero or more ones (`[^0]*`) followed by any mix of odd-even and even-odd blocks — sort of like `(odd-even|even-odd)(odd-even|even-odd)...`, but for any amount (zero or more) of either odd-even or even-odd.  How could you do that?